# Laravel: Eager loading user-specific rows

Tags: mysql, laravel

Let's say I am developing stackoverflow.

When a user visits the site, threads must be loaded. But it's not just the threads, I also need the information, whether a user has already voted on a thread or not and how he voted (up/down).

Models: Thread, Vote

Now how can I eager load the votes on the threads? I know I can eager load ALL votes using $with on the Thread model, but I don't need to load thousands of votes with each thread. I only need to know if this one user, who is logged in, has voted and how.

I would like to know the best approach to solve these kind of problems. Thank you!

edit: is this maybe the solution?

```
Thread::with([

'vote' => function($q) use ($userId = Auth::user()->id) {

$q->where('user_id',$userId)

}

])->get();
```

and if it is - how can I tell the Thread model itself to always apply this condition? Because I might have many different places where I need to eager load the votes from the user and it would be always the same condition.

Update:

I went ahead and subscribed again to Laracasts to be able to understand the solution provided here: https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-voting-app/episodes/19?autoplay=true

It goes like this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#subquery-selects

```
Thread::addSelect(['user_has_voted' => Vote::select('id')
    ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->whereColumn('thread_id', 'thread.id')
    ->limit(1)
])->get();
```

This works. The `user_has_voted` column is null whenever the user has not voted. However, I would like to do this on the model side of things, because I have many different places where I get the threads and I always need the column. How would I go about that?

Comment: Laracasts has a series on [building a voting app](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-voting-app), [this episode](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-voting-app/episodes/19) in particular might be of interest. They have the source code available for free if you’re not subscribed.

Comment: thanks, interesting. But the source code looks like a n+1 problem. Look at the idea.php's `isVotedByUser()`.

Comment: @Peppermintology sorry, I went ahead and bought the subscription to understand this better. Now the problem I have is that I need this property everywhere, so on the model itself and not on the query.

Comment: @Peppermintology I updated my original post.